# Clustering users in R; monitoring changes in cluster structure to detect users that "disappear" or "move" clusters

Tags: r, for-loop, cluster-analysis, k-means, prediction

I am working with a longitudinal user event generated data set and I am trying to cluster the user ID's in the data at a Month-Year level using k-means. The idea is that I want to see how users disappear from or move into different cluster archetypes over the different timepoints.

Here is code I have so far, which contains a mock dataframe and the clustering process.

```
library(Pareto)
library(uuid)
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)
library(zoo)
#generating the user ID variable
set.seed(1)
n_users <- 1300
n_rows <- 365000

relative_probs <- rPareto(n = n_users, t = 1, alpha = 0.3, truncation = 500) 
unique_ids <- UUIDgenerate(n = n_users)

id_sample <- sample(unique_ids, size = n_rows, prob = relative_probs, replace = TRUE)

id_sample


df<-data.frame(id_sample)


#creating the date variable
df$Date<-sample(seq(as.Date("2015-01-01"), as.Date("2017-12-31"), by = "1 day"), 
                size = n_rows,replace = T)

#creating a numeric value called Duration; this will be a feature in the clustering
df$Duration<-sample(0:3000, nrow(df), replace = T)
df<-df%>%arrange(Date)
#getting Month-Year
df$MonthYear<-as.Date(as.yearmon(df$Date, "%m/%Y"))
MonthYear<-unique(df$MonthYear)

#empty results df
resultsdf<-data.frame()

for (i in MonthYear) {
  #getting variables for clustering. I need to cluster based on the number of  times the User appears in the data i.e. "Count"
  #the second variable is the mean duration for each User ID i.e. "MeanDur" 
  #the third and final variable is the standard deviation of duration i.e. "SDDur"
  
df_filtered<-df%>%
filter(MonthYear<=i)

  callerData<-df_filtered%>%
    group_by(id_sample)%>%
    summarise(Count=n(),MeanDur=mean(Duration),SDDur=sd(Duration))
 #convert NA to zero's
  callerData$SDDur[is.na(callerData$SDDur)]<-0.0 
  #scale data
  scaledData<-scale(callerData[,2:4])
  
  set.seed(20)
  clust<-kmeans(scaledData, centers= 5,nstart = 15)
  #pinning cluster number back onto callerData
  callerData$Cluster<-clust$cluster
  #getting cluster means and creating a rank order based on "Count" 
  callerData_centers<-callerData%>%
    group_by(Cluster)%>%
    summarise(Count=mean(Count),MeanDur=mean(MeanDur),SDDur=mean(SDDur))%>%
    arrange(Count)
    
callerDate_centers$Rank<-c(1:5)
  #Once the new ranking variable is created, I then use the code below to consistently name the clusters based on their rank
  setDT(callerData_centers)[Rank==1,ClusName:="Cluster 1"]
  callerData_centers[Rank==2,ClusName:="Cluster 2"]
  callerData_centers[Rank==3,ClusName:="Cluster 3"]
  callerData_centers[Rank==4,ClusName:="Cluster 4"]
  callerData_centers[Rank==5,ClusName:="Cluster 5"]
#get the ClusName variable and the Cluster; this is then used to merge the new name back onto callerData
  callerData_vars<-callerData_centers%>%select(Cluster,ClusName)
  callerData<-merge(callerData,callerData_vars, by="Cluster")
 
    newVars<-callerData%>%
    select(CallerId,ClusterName)%>%
    mutate(MonthYear=i)
 
resultsdf<-rbind(resultsdf,newVars)
}


head(resultsdf)
```

So the code filters backward from `MonthYear<=i` and clusters it. But what I would like to know is there a way for me to detect if certain users move from one cluster to another or disappear? Say for instance, `id_sample=abcdef` is in cluster 1 for 7 months but then moves to cluster 4 after the 7 months. How could I detect this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to change your code a bit to make it run. `CallerId` and `ClusterName` are not part of `callerData`. So first run this:

```
library(Pareto)
library(uuid)
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)
library(zoo)
library(dplyr)
#generating the user ID variable
#generating the user ID variable
set.seed(1)
n_users <- 1300
n_rows <- 365000

relative_probs <-
  rPareto(
    n = n_users,
    t = 1,
    alpha = 0.3,
    truncation = 500
  )
unique_ids <- UUIDgenerate(n = n_users)

id_sample <-
  sample(unique_ids,
         size = n_rows,
         prob = relative_probs,
         replace = TRUE)

id_sample


df <- data.frame(id_sample)


#creating the date variable
df$Date <-
  sample(seq(as.Date("2015-01-01"), as.Date("2017-12-31"), by = "1 day"),
         size = n_rows,
         replace = T)

#creating a numeric value called Duration; this will be a feature in the clustering
df$Duration <- sample(0:3000, nrow(df), replace = T)
df <- df %>% arrange(Date)
#getting Month-Year
df$MonthYear <- as.Date(as.yearmon(df$Date, "%m/%Y"))
MonthYear <- unique(df$MonthYear)

#empty results df
resultsdf <- data.frame()

for (i in MonthYear) {
  #getting variables for clustering. I need to cluster based on the number of  times the User appears in the data i.e. "Count"
  #the second variable is the mean duration for each User ID i.e. "MeanDur"
  #the third and final variable is the standard deviation of duration i.e. "SDDur"
  
  df_filtered <- df %>%
    filter(MonthYear <= i)
  
  callerData <- df_filtered %>%
    group_by(id_sample) %>%
    summarise(
      Count = n(),
      MeanDur = mean(Duration),
      SDDur = sd(Duration)
    )
  #convert NA to zero's
  callerData$SDDur[is.na(callerData$SDDur)] <- 0.0
  #scale data
  scaledData <- scale(callerData[, 2:4])
  
  set.seed(20)
  clust <- kmeans(scaledData, centers = 5, nstart = 15)
  #pinning cluster number back onto callerData
  callerData$Cluster <- clust$cluster
  #getting cluster means and creating a rank order based on "Count"
  callerData_centers <- callerData %>%
    group_by(Cluster) %>%
    summarise(
      Count = mean(Count),
      MeanDur = mean(MeanDur),
      SDDur = mean(SDDur)
    ) %>%
    arrange(Count)
  
  callerData_centers$Rank <- c(1:5)
  #Once the new ranking variable is created, I then use the code below to consistently name the clusters based on their rank
  setDT(callerData_centers)[Rank == 1, ClusName := "Cluster 1"]
  callerData_centers[Rank == 2, ClusName := "Cluster 2"]
  callerData_centers[Rank == 3, ClusName := "Cluster 3"]
  callerData_centers[Rank == 4, ClusName := "Cluster 4"]
  callerData_centers[Rank == 5, ClusName := "Cluster 5"]
  #get the ClusName variable and the Cluster; this is then used to merge the new name back onto callerData
  callerData_vars <-
    callerData_centers %>% select(Cluster, ClusName)
  callerData <- merge(callerData, callerData_vars, by = "Cluster")
  
  newVars <- callerData %>%
    select(id_sample, ClusName) %>%
    mutate(MonthYear = i)
  
  resultsdf <- rbind(resultsdf, newVars)
}
```

Then, you can reshape your dataframe to wide format and see that some of the ids will jump from cluster to cluster (e.g. in row 5 from column 4 to 5)

```
# long to wide
dfwide <- data.table::dcast(resultsdf, formula = id_sample ~ MonthYear, value.var = 'ClusName')
colnames(dfwide)[2:37] <- paste0('Date_', MonthYear)

> dfwide[1:5, 1:5]
                             id_sample Date_2015-01-01 Date_2015-02-01 Date_2015-03-01 Date_2015-04-01
1 0025a4ba-d620-4ffc-a82d-660354c2b21d            <NA>       Cluster 3       Cluster 3       Cluster 3
2 00403759-46d8-4c60-b298-a57e6299b2ca       Cluster 3       Cluster 3       Cluster 3       Cluster 3
3 005e6e19-8e02-4326-993d-1fffa0b70c67       Cluster 4       Cluster 4       Cluster 4       Cluster 4
4 007c99ef-7e37-42c0-8883-90c275c03eab       Cluster 3       Cluster 3       Cluster 3       Cluster 3
5 007e70f9-d960-4679-8088-a1065ea9835c       Cluster 3       Cluster 3       Cluster 3       Cluster 2
```

You can then check which IDs did not stay within one cluster:

```
# check if they stay in their cluster:
dfwide_subset <- na.omit(dfwide) # drop rows with NAs 

res <- dfwide_subset[, c(2:5)] == dfwide_subset[, 2]
res <- data.frame('id_sample' = dfwide_subset$id_sample,
                  'switches_cluster' = rowSums(!res))

> head(res)
                             id_sample switches_cluster
2 00403759-46d8-4c60-b298-a57e6299b2ca                0
3 005e6e19-8e02-4326-993d-1fffa0b70c67                0
4 007c99ef-7e37-42c0-8883-90c275c03eab                0
5 007e70f9-d960-4679-8088-a1065ea9835c                1
6 00b90528-5ee1-40f2-a2ba-5b6fc4b3707f                0
8 00d5cf0c-e2b4-4ed6-a69c-776b83ff8697                0
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. It looks really clear/ I am going to try it in a moment. I was wondering if I can ask one last thing. When an ```id_sample``` changes cluster, can there be an additional column in ```res``` which states the MonthYear or date variable when this happens? And if it is not too much to ask, two more columns which states the previous cluster and the new cluster that the user has jumped to. Only if it is not too much trouble. I think it would help complement any subsequent analysis that I have to do. This is great so far though, thank you!

Comment: `dfwide_subset[, c(2:5)] == dfwide_subset[, 2]` checks if the cluster in colums 2:5 is equal to the cluster in column 2 and gives a visual representation of that check. If it is `FALSE` then the cluster is different from the first column.

Another way to do it would be to lag the cluster by one period for each id in your resultsdf and see if it is equal to the current cluster. Should be easily doable using data.table.